# ImageMagick's resizeImage cause error "The connection was reset"

Tags: php, xampp, imagemagick, imagick, php-7.4

I have trouble using simpliest PHP (php version 7.4, XAMPP environment) code for image resize, with ImageMagick. It causes Apache server error The connection was reset (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET).

Here is code:

```
<?php

function resizeImage($imagePath) {
    
        $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
        $imagick->resizeImage(320,240, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1); // trouble line
        
        header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
        //$imagick->writeImage("./output.png");
        exit;
    
}

$imagePath = '/xampp/htdocs/devel/images/tumb500.jpg';
resizeImage($imagePath);

?>
```

**Update:**
Error in Apache logs related to this is:

```
PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against ImageMagick version 1799 but version 1803 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
```

But - checked and I have same error on other server where this code work properly.

And also, I tried with different (older) versions of ImageMagick and I have same error all the time.

Also to mention that other Imagick methods work properly.

Can you help me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Check Apaches error log and see if there's any error messages in there.

Comment: sure, please check updated part of my post.

Comment: Do you have more than one version of ImageMagick on your system? Perhaps one compiled for PHP and then another somewhere?

Comment: @fmw42 you are a genius! i installed several versions of ImageMagick, and I did uninstalled them. And path in Windows system was correct. But! In one dir of uninstalled ImageMagick, several dll files where left, and it looks like they where in use, not the proper one. Thank you!!! :-)